# How to open a file from different directory in perl?

Tags: perl, directory

i am very new to perl, so I would like to know if there is a way to

1. Open a file from a different directory (not the same directory as the perl script.pl for example)
2. open multiple files that have the same name, e.g sameName.txt, under the same parent directory but have different sub directory, e.g

   ```
   directory:
   - /alias/a/1/sameName.txt
   - /alias/b/1/sameName.txt
   - /alias/c/1/sameName.txt
   ```

   for example as above, but at the same time, there is also the same file, sameName.txt in other directory which I don't want, e.g

   ```
   directory:
   - /alias/a/2/sameName.txt
   - /alias/b/2/sameName.txt
   - /alias/c/2/sameName.txt
   ```

   How can I automatically search the directory which the user want, using user input `<STDIN>`, not hard-coded into the script perl.pl for example, the user want all the sameName.txt files which had in the directory /1/sameName.txt, but with different parent, which is a b and c folder. I want to make it automatically read those files sameName.txt which is located in different folder, so that the user doesn't need to adjust the script every time there is a new path like d/1/sameName.txt created.
3. if I want the data in these files with the same name with different directories, should I loop it, save into arrays for example, or should i copy all the contents and append it to a single file? because i need to match the data between the files which i have done the script.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest that you see the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and then look around the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  While people are willing to help out with all kinds of inquiries, the questions are generally expected to be specific and about your code. In particular, requests for code or tutorials on basics are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/function/open.html) a file from anywhere that you like.

The filename argument is a path and you associate that with a filehandle to access its data:

```
  my $path = '/alias/a/1/sameName.txt';
  open my $fh, '<', $path or die "Could not open $path: $!";
```

2. Perl doesn't care if another file in a different directory has the same name.

You distinguish them with a different file handle:

```
  my $path2 = '/alias/a/2/sameName.txt';
  open my $fh2, '<', $path or die "Could not open $path: $!";
```

You can construct that second path by grabbing the filename portion of the first path and putting it together with the other directory. These are core Perl modules that should already be there:

```
  use File::Basename;
  use File::Spec::Functions;

  my $other_dir = '/alias/a/2';
  my $basename = basename( $path );   # sameName.txt
  my $path2 = catfile( $other_dir, $basename );
```

3. Not quite sure what you are trying to do.

You might be interested in [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com) or the other resources at [learn.perl.org](https://learn.perl.org).

Comment: I am sorry, my 2nd question is not fully explained. How can I automatically search the directory which the user want, not hard-coded into the script perl.pl for example, the user want all the sameName.txt files which had in the directory /1/sameName.txt, but with different parent, which is a b and c folder. I want to make it automatically read those files sameName.txt which is located in different folder, so that the user can't adjust the script every time there is a new path like d/1/sameName.txt created.

Comment: @DanialHaris You got answers here, and far more than you normally would on such a broad question.  (This site is not a good fit for introductory explanations, but is rather for specific problems with your code.)  I encourage you to work with what you got and try to do yourself what is not "_fully explained_," and to see the materials linked in the answer.

Comment: Update your question instead of putting clarifications in comments.